# Justify items in Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

### [Codepen](https://codepen.io/khegay/pen/BroMXJ)

HTML:

```
<nav class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="child">first item</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">another item</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">and another</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">last item</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

### Problem

first-child shouldn't have left padding.
last-child shouldn't have right padding.

[image]
[image]

Comment: remove flex-grow:1

Comment: Have you tried: `justify-content: space-evenly`?

Comment: Please show all relevant code, including HTML code as well. What you have posted so far is not enough to determine what the issue is.

Comment: please make a fiddle @ jsfiddle.net

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the below to achieve this,

```
.parent :first-child {
    text-align: left;
    flex-grow: .5;
}

.parent :last-child {
    text-align: right;
    flex-grow: .5;
}
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/dmYEwY)

Hope this helps.